# SPSS: GPL - stacked histogram colors

Tags: colors, spss

Using SPSS, when a stacked histogram is generated using the chart-builder option, the GPL code that is generated to determine the colors differentiating the stacks appears as such

ELEMENT: interval.stack(position(VAR_1*COUNT), **color.interior(VAR_2)**, 
    shape.interior(shape.square))

However, the default colors are pretty rough, and I'd like to add some of my company's "proprietary" colors for thematic reasons.

Is it possible to specify specific HEX colors in the color.interior command? Such as color.interior(color."color_1", color."color_2))??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are many color constants you can use without resorting to hex codes.  These are listed in the GPL Constats > Color Constants section of the help.  They can even be blended, e.g,, color(color.red+color.green).

If you know the RGB hex values you want, though, you can refer to these, e.g.,
color."FF0000"

You can also change the color cycle palette via Edit > Options > Charts> Colors.  You can select common, named colors, select from swatches or set RGB or HSB colors there.

In GPL, you would normally map the color values to data values using the SCALE statement and the color function, e.g.,

SCALE: cat(aesthetic(aesthetic.color), include("0", "1"), map(("0", color.FF00FF), ("1", color.blue)))
  ELEMENT: point(position(jobtime*salary), color.exterior(minority))